# Prove that a simple ordering implies a partial ordering

Tags: order-theory

I am having difficulty proving theorem 55 section 3.2 page 73 of Patrick Suppes Axiomatic Set Theory. This is the theorem to be proven. (**R** is a simple ordering) ⇒ (**R** is a partial ordering). He states that this theorem is obvious but this is only the case for the antisymmetry and transitivity of **R**. Definition of a simple ordering **R** is [(**R** is antisymmetric  in F**A**) ● (**R** is transitive in F**A**) ● (**R** is strongly connected in F**A**)]. Definition of a partial ordering **R** is [(**R** is reflexive in F**A**) ● (**R** is transitive in F**A**) ● (**R** is antisymmetric in F**A**)]. So clearly all that needs to be proven is that (**R** is reflexive in F**A**). How do you do this? I tried a conditional proof. Please answer in detail.

Comment: FA is the field of the set A, defined as the union of the domain of A and the range of A.

Comment: But what is $A$? Also important, what's his definition of "strongly connected"? It might follow trivially from that, depending on how it's phrased.

Comment: A is any set. The definition of a strongly connected set R is (∀x)(∀y)[x, y∈ A → (x R y ∨ y R x)] where R is any set but usually in this context a mathematical relation.

Comment: Then you probably mean $F(R)$ in your problem, no?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $R$ is a simple ordering (antisymmetric, transitive and strongly connected: $x,y \in A \rightarrow xRy \lor yRx$). To see that $R$ is a partial ordering, we already have transitive and antisymmetric. So we need only reflexiveness. Well, strongly connected with $y = x$ gives immediately that $xRx$ for all $x$. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in A$. Because $R$ is strongly connected, either $xRx$ or $xRx$. That is, $R$ is reflexive.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for. Since xRx or xRx by disjunctive tautology in logic is logically identical to xRX. Therefore, through conditional proof, R is Reflexive.

Comment: That's right. & you're welcome.